# How to map storage.userId and idToken in Google Assistant actionSdk

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, account-linking

1. Hi,  We have created a bot where user interact with the bot. so our
   bot has two type of queries static and dynamic queries. if user asks
   static query we don't ask for SIGN IN but if user ask for dynamic
   query than we ask user to SIGN IN and redirect to SIGN IN page than
   we ask mobile no and dob and send OTP to user and than verify the
   user and send back a token in response which we get in further
   request. The problem is let use suppose user came on our our bot and
   asked static query so i store the chat of user to my db initially I
   create a userId for user like this conv.user.storage.userId =
   'unique_id' and store this unique_id in my db to identify the user
   next time and send back. Next time same bot get same userId and keep
   updating my chat in db for this userId. Now the problem comes when
   users asks a dynamic query than I have to redirect user to our
   account linking page. user is redirectd to account linking page and
   user fill his mobile no. and DOb and we send a otp to usermobile.
   When our SendOtp api is called I create a userId and store in
   databse but I want the userId which I set before for static queries
   (conv.user.storeage.userId) this one. How can I get this Id. Can we
   pass this userId as params to when to ask for SIGN In (conv.ask(new
   SignIn('To get your account details'))) and get this static query
   userId in my SendOtp API. I need same ID to send further to update
   chat.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a SignIn request, you cannot provide any additional data in that request. However, you are able to provide this behavior when your Action gets a callback. You will get a [Sign In event](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in) that can be set to when the user signs in. At that point you can add your additional logic to connect the user's account on your backend with the account ID in userStorage.

Here's an example of what it may look like.

```js
app.handle('linkAccount', async conv => {
  let payload = conv.headers.authorization;
  if (payload) {
    // Perform account merge
    await performAccountMerge(payload.email, conv.user.storage.userId)
  }
});

async function performAccountMerge(authorizedEmail, savedUserId) {
  await saveInDatabaseForEmail(authorizedEmail, savedUserId)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Nick. But I want the userId which I set initially in some other API. i am using a sendOTP API i want this userId there. So i can use this useid to map user.

Comment: actionApp.intent('actions.intent.SIGN_IN', async (conv, params, signin) => {
  const idToken = conv.request.user.idToken
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const userID = _getGAUserId(conv)
    const userData = await _getByUserId(userID)
    if (!userData) {
        conv.close("I won't be able to save your data, Please Login first")
        return
      } 
      // DATABASE LOGIC HERE
  } else {
    conv.close("I won't be able to save your data, Please Login first")
  }})

Comment: If you have a previous ID from user storage, you can merge the two after the fact but cannot provide this value when creating a sign-in request.